# Hard drive capacity showed in Disk Management is inconsistent

Tags: windows-7, hard-drive, partitioning, boot-camp

If you look at the highlighted boxes in below image, you can see box 1 shows `C:` drive has 697 GB of capacity, and box 2 shows the same drive having 354 GB of capacity.

[image]

[image: Drive info in Mac]

The drive capacities don't add up. Where is the remaining space?

I have done Mac disk repair and Windows `chkdsk`. Neither shows a problem with the drive.

Background story: (Ignore if you dont need it)
I got a Macbook Pro (2010 model).
Installed a 1TB HDD in it.
Divided it into 3 partitions.
1 for Mac boot partition, 1 for Windows boot partition and 1 for data storage (NTFS).
All was working good until I recently upgraded Mac to Yosemite.
After the upgrade, as you can see in the image, there is only NTFS partition.
Looks like Yosemite installer packed both the NTFS partitions into one.
I cant see any data that was in the data partition.

Comment: Things to check/do… 1. **Never** let Windows mess with Boot Camp partitions, it will break them. 2. Check from OS X if that drive is a Core Storage/Logical Volume Group. If so, it can only have maximum 4 partitions without some fiddling in Terminal.

Comment: I'm making this up; perhaps the partition size (specified by the MBR) is different than the volume size (specified by numbers that are stored in the header of the volume - exact details would vary based on which filesystem is used).  This could theoretically be done; after a filesystem volume is created, the numbers on the MBR could be re-sized.  It would just seem weird for a volume-creator (FORMAT) to not make a volume 100% of the size of the partition that was specified by the editing software (FDISK).  But maybe boot-camp, dealing with "non-native" ("other OS") code, does some weird stuff?